# How to check if a folder exists in google drive? (ruby client)

Tags: google-drive-api

It seems I can only return the contents of a folder, but no information about the folder itself.

```
  results = client.execute({
    :api_method => drive.files.list,
    :q => "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' AND trashed=false AND title='#{app_folder_name}'",
    :maxResults => 1
  })
```

The returned results.to_hash["items"] array is populated with the contents of the folder (including sub folders and files). How can I just get information about the folder itself? All I want to do is check if it exists. And it also seems that maxResults is getting ignored as the array has more than one entry.

Answer (score 0):

A folder on Google Drive is like a regular file but with a special MIME type ("application/vnd.google-apps.folder"). Once you have the id of the folder, you can access its metadata with a [`files.get`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get) request:

```
##
# Print a file's metadata.
#
# @param [Google::APIClient] client
#   Authorized client instance
# @param [String] file_id
#   ID of file to print
# @return nil
def print_file(client, file_id)
  drive = client.discovered_api('drive', 'v2')
  result = client.execute(
    :api_method => @drive.files.get,
    :parameters => { 'fileId' => file_id })
  if result.status == 200
    file = result.data
    puts "Title: #{file.title}"
    puts "Description: #{file.description}"
    puts "MIME type: #{file.mime_type}"
  else
    puts "An error occurred: #{result.data['error']['message']}"
  end
end
```

Comment: What if I don't know the id... at least in my test environment, I want to check if the folder exists based only on it's name and parent folder.

Comment: File and folder names are not unique so that might not be the safest approach. Anyway, your code should return the metadata for the folders and not the folder content. Can you try the same request with the OAuth 2.0 Playground (https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground)?